# python If statement Syntax error?

Tags: python

new to python, currently reading [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and trying to run the following code from the book:

```
def buildConnectionString(params):
   """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters.

      Returns string."""
      return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])
if __name__ == "__main__":
      myParams = {"server":"mpilgrim", \
                  "database":"master", \
                  "uid":"sa", \
                  "pwd":"secret" \
                  }
    print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

Now when i hit enter, Python shell says the `if` statement has a syntax error?? I'm running Python 2.7.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. posting the (full and exact) error you get will let people help you faster :)

Comment: Have you made sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: this indentation stuff is driving me crazy. can someone suggest me a editor to use? i'm baffled of why i cant print this statement with these indentation errors

Answer (score 3):

The code itself is working (I just tried it). A possible reason for errors is inconsistent indentation. It seems that your lines start with different numbers of spaces (or tabs). Try changing the the blank space in the beginning of each indented line to, say, four spaces, and try running the script again.

Comment: what environment do you use to code in? sorry i'm  new and lost that people are telling me not to code in the shell? where am i supposed to code then?

Comment: @Apprentice Programmer: I usually use Python IDLE or Geany.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in line 5: the `return` should be indented at the level of the opening `"""` of the function.

However, you shouldn't be entering that code in the shell - do it in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your indentation levels are wrong. Looking at your pasted code, I would guess that you are mixing tabs and blanks, so you are using a "bad" editor. Use an editor which replaces tabs by blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your issue and i am uploading the proper syntax of code

```
def buildConnectionString(params):
   return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams = {"server":"mpilgrim", \
                  "database":"master", \
                  "uid":"sa", \
                  "pwd":"secret" \
                }
print (buildConnectionString(myParams))
```

I hope this will helpful as well as useful for you !!

[image: Output]